# Retrieve all users from domain

Tags: api, jpa, provisioning

My idea is to retrieve all users from Google app domain using Java.

I retrieved all the users using Provisioning API but when I tried to store the data in the table using JPA, it's returning a timeout error.

I don't know how to store the entire details at a stretch. Please Help me.

Comment: perhaps post code, and the error, and more explanation....